# calculate variance in sales between years aggregated by month in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a sales table with two columns in PostgreSQL: sales and date. For example with the following data:

```
Date         Sales
2017-02-05   600
2017-03-01   800
2018-01-10   300
2018-02-02   500
2018-02-03   300
2018-03-01   800
```

And I need to calculate a variance in sales between years aggregated by month.

The result should be like that:

```
Month  sales_2017   sales_2018   variance
Jan    null         300          300
Feb    600          800          200
Mar    800          800          0
```

What a query should be to get the result above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9be11a4192b0714f215a05662c8f9d69)

```
SELECT
    to_char(to_date(date_part::text, 'MM'), 'Mon') as month,                           -- 3
    sales_2017,
    sales_2018,
    COALESCE(sales_2018, 0) - COALESCE(sales_2017, 0) as variance                      -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT
        date_part('month', sales_date),                                                -- 1
        SUM(sales) FILTER (WHERE date_part('year', sales_date) = 2017) as sales_2017,  -- 2
        SUM(sales) FILTER (WHERE date_part('year', sales_date) = 2018) as sales_2018
    FROM
        sales
    GROUP BY 1                                                                         -- 1
)s
ORDER BY date_part
```

1. `date_part` gives the month number of a date. This allows grouping by month without the date's year
2. This is a simple pivot function: `SUM` the values with a certain filter (in this case the filter is the year). This allows aggregating only the values for single years
3. Calculating the month name from the month number (recreate a `date` type with `to_date` and then format it with `to_char`). The `'Mon'` formatter gives the three letter abbreviation.
4. Calculation the `variance` from the previous calculated columns. `COALESCE` converts NULL values into number `0`

[Postgres date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what I need!